# calculate the total value in a object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

```
{
        "id" : "12345"
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "lighting",
        "value" : 24324
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "12345"
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "equipment",
        "value" : 24324
    }, 
    {
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "fans",
        "value" : 24324
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "12345"
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "distribution",
        "value" : 24324
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "12345"
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "chiller",
        "value" : 24324
    }, 
    {
       "id" : "12345"
        "energy" : "electricity",
        "type" : "other",
        "value" : 24324
    }
```

This is my query to find total value. I use $project.

```
  db.invoices.aggregate([
    {
    $project: {
        total: {$sum : "$value"}
    }
}])
```

I try to find the total value. Can any one please help to find the total value. also find the value with the Id wise.

Comment: db.products.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$type',total:{$sum:'$value'}}}])

Comment: Thanks  @Joel Garcia Nuño but how do I find the total that Id: "12345"

Comment: Try to filter in the _id: <expresion> , gonna be equals than 12345 id, but one of them doesn't have it, may you need to check if it's null don't do anything